# How do I prevent infinite loops with useEffect when the function relies on a value that it sets?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a React component that makes a request to the backend to get a list of transactions.  There is pagination involved, so the payload will return a cursor, that can be used the next time that the request should be made.

```
useEffect((): void => {
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: QueryTransactions,
    variables: {
      id: accountId,
      after: cursor
    }
  });

  setData(data.data)
  setCursor(data.nextCursor)
}, [accountId, cursor]);
```

My problem is that I am setting the cursor each time I receive a payload from the backend, but that cursor value is in the hook dependencies. This makes the effect run again.

How do I get around this infinite loop?

Comment: do you need the cursor to be in state? i.e can the cursor be changed by the UI? or can it only be updated by the API response

Comment: At what point(S) do you actually want the effect to run

Comment: The cursor that is used to make the next call to the server is returned by the current call to the server.

Comment: The next call to the server will be triggered by the user scrolling down the page, as well as the initial call to the server.

Comment: I was able to work around the issue by refactoring my code, but want to see if there is a way to prevent the effect from automatically being called when a dependency changes.

Comment: it seems maybe you dont even need to store the cursor in state. Just store the cursor in a ref.